# unable to perform calculations using r data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

I have a huge data frame, last 30 rows are below:

```
libary(data.table)
```

dput(p)

```
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(1367516015, 1367516045, 1367516075, 
1367516105, 1367516135, 1367516165, 1367516195, 1367516225, 1367516255, 
1367516285, 1367516315, 1367516345, 1367516375, 1367516405, 1367516435, 
1367516465, 1367516495, 1367516525, 1367516555, 1367516585, 1367516615, 
1367516645, 1367516675, 1367516705, 1367516735, 1367516765, 1367516795, 
1367516825, 1367516855, 1367516885), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), LPAR = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("cigp01a4a004", "cigp01b4a002", 
"cigp01b4a004", "cigp04a4a002", "cigp04a4a004", "cigp04b4a002", 
"cigp04b4a004"), class = "factor"), ENT = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
), USR_SYS_CPU_PCT = c(79L, 80L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 76L, 79L, 82L, 
81L, 80L, 79L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 80L, 
81L, 80L, 78L, 78L, 83L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 87L), ENT_PCT = c(706.8, 
693.8, 570.1, 641.5, 558.5, 601.5, 674.3, 742.3, 668.9, 722.6, 
679.1, 677.2, 548.5, 644.6, 689.3, 716.1, 709.5, 767.3, 753.7, 
786.4, 684.2, 735.1, 688.2, 676.6, 645.6, 788, 859.5, 832.6, 
883.1, 872.2), PHYSICAL_CPU_USED = c(3.53, 3.47, 2.85, 3.21, 
2.79, 3.01, 3.37, 3.71, 3.34, 3.61, 3.4, 3.39, 2.74, 3.22, 3.45, 
3.58, 3.55, 3.84, 3.77, 3.93, 3.42, 3.68, 3.44, 3.38, 3.23, 3.94, 
4.3, 4.16, 4.42, 4.36), PROC_QUE = c(12L, 13L, 19L, 16L, 11L, 
13L, 17L, 14L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 22L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
26L, 26L, 15L, 43L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 23L), RELATIVE_CORES = c(3.53, 
3.47, 2.85, 3.21, 2.79, 3.01, 3.37, 3.71, 3.34, 3.61, 3.4, 3.39, 
2.74, 3.22, 3.45, 3.58, 3.55, 3.84, 3.77, 3.93, 3.42, 3.68, 3.44, 
3.38, 3.23, 3.94, 4.3, 4.16, 4.42, 4.36), USED_CORES = c(2.7887, 
2.776, 2.1945, 2.4717, 2.1483, 2.2876, 2.6623, 3.0422, 2.7054, 
2.888, 2.686, 2.6103, 2.1098, 2.4794, 2.7255, 2.8282, 2.84, 3.1488, 
3.0914, 3.2619, 2.736, 2.9808, 2.752, 2.6364, 2.5194, 3.2702, 
3.698, 3.6192, 3.8896, 3.7932)), .Names = c("DATE", "LPAR", "ENT", 
"USR_SYS_CPU_PCT", "ENT_PCT", "PHYSICAL_CPU_USED", "PROC_QUE", 
"RELATIVE_CORES", "USED_CORES"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

when I like calcualate some values using data.table as below:

```
p<-data.table(p)
p<-p[,RELATIVE_PERCENT:=ifelse(ENT_PCT>100, (USED_CORES/ENT)*100, USR_SYS_CPU_PCT), by= c("DATE", "LPAR")]
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(x, , `:=`(RELATIVE_PERCENT, ifelse(ENT_PCT > 100,  : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would
  impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of
  the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead
  of 1)
```

what does this error mean? How can I get around this error?

Comment: Using data.table 1.8.8 I don't get such an error when running the above code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your `ifelse` statement returns `integer` type for some values and `numeric` (double) for some other entries. And `data.table` complains about the mismatch in the column type as it expects the coercion to be performed by the user (for performance reasons as given in the error). So, just wrap it around with `as.numeric` so that all values will be converted to double.

```
p <- p[,RELATIVE_PERCENT := as.numeric(ifelse(ENT_PCT>100, (USED_CORES/ENT)*100, 
                      USR_SYS_CPU_PCT)), by= c("DATE", "LPAR")]
```

Answer (score 3):

I did this:

```
sapply(p, class)
```

and noticed that one of my columns was integer. Then I did this:

```
x<-x[,RELATIVE_PERCENT:=ifelse(ENT_PCT>100, ((USED_CORES/ENT)*100), as.numeric(USR_SYS_CPU_PCT)), by= c("DATE", "LPAR")]
```

and it is money