# Indexing by multiple criteria between 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, match, aggregate

I have the following data frame:

```
id    day  event
1     1    1
1     3    1
2     1    0
2     4    0
2     9    0
2     15   0
3     2    0
3     5    0
4     1    1
4     8    1
4     11   1
```

What i want is when an event has a value zero then all the event values become one except from the last one(by date). So the output should be the following:

```
id    day  event
1     1    1
1     3    1
2     1    1
2     4    1
2     9    1
2     15   0
3     2    1
3     5    0
4     1    1
4     8    1
4     11   1
```

Any help?

Comment: I believe it is `event` what he is referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', `if` `any` of the 'event' is 0 (`!event`) for that particular 'id', we replicate 1 for the length of that group -1 (`.N-1`) and concatenate with 0 or `else` to return the 'event' value, assign (`:=`) to update the 'event' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, event :=if(any(!event)) c(rep(1L, .N-1),0L) else event, by = id]


df1
#    id day event
# 1:  1   1     1
# 2:  1   3     1
# 3:  2   1     1
# 4:  2   4     1
# 5:  2   9     1
# 6:  2  15     0
# 7:  3   2     1
# 8:  3   5     0
# 9:  4   1     1
#10:  4   8     1
#11:  4  11     1
```

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'id' and change the 'event' column by taking the `lead` of the logical vector that is replicated and add with another logical vector (`all(event)`).

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(event= lead(rep(any(!event), n()), default=0) + all(event))
#     id   day event
#   (int) (int) (dbl)
#1      1     1     1
#2      1     3     1
#3      2     1     1
#4      2     4     1
#5      2     9     1
#6      2    15     0
#7      3     2     1
#8      3     5     0
#9      4     1     1
#10     4     8     1
#11     4    11     1
```

Comment: Thanks. Just for the record: I had the following problem with this line of code( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361225/unable-to-perform-calculations-using-r-data-table-package  ). So I included the if statement inside to as.numeric().